# How to use nodeload in Drupal 7 to print referred node field?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am in a node, I created a field using "References" module to relate one content type to another. Now... The 2 content type are "PRACTISE" (a node with title, description ecc...) and "TECHNOLOGY", a node with just logo images. I want to show related logo into node--practise.tpl.php. How can i do this in DP7?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it directly in the template file, instead you'd be better off implementing `hook_preprocess_node` in your theme's template.php file to pass the logo(s) in as a variable. The logic is the same either way:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $node = $vars['node'];

  if ($node->type == 'practise') {
    $related_node_nid = $node->field_related_field_name['und'][0]['nid'];
    $related_node = node_load($related_node_nid);

    $logos = '';
    foreach ($related_node->field_logo_field_name['und'] as $img) {
      $logos .= theme('image', array('path' => $img['uri'], 'alt' => 'Alt text'));
    }
    $vars['related_logos'] = $logos;
  }
}
```

Then in your template.php file you will have the variable `$logos` which will contain the list of logos you built up in the `preprocess` function. Obviously you can tailer the HTML to suit your needs, and you need to swap in the correct field names for `field_related_field_name` and `field_logo_field_name`.